# Weird syntax for push_back function in std::vector

Tags: c++, initialization, stdvector, list-initialization

I came across the following syntax for the `push_back` function. `Vertex` is just a structure that holds the three floats x, y and z. The second line looks just like would write it. But the first line looks weird to me. In the video where this was explained it was said that this is done with the member initializer list but it looks more like implicit conversion. I am just confused by the curly brackets there. Can anyone explain why this syntax works?

```
std::vector<Vertex> vertices;

vertices.push_back({ 1, 2, 3 });
vertices.push_back(Vertex(1, 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not member initializer list but [copy list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11).

> 7) in a function call expression, with *braced-init-list* used as an argument and list-initialization initializes the function parameter

`vertices.push_back()` expects an `Vertex` as the argument, the *braced-init-list* `{ 1, 2, 3 }` is used to construct a temporary `Vertex` which is passed to `push_back` later. As you said, you can think it as implicit conversion too, i.e. the conversion from the *braced-init-list* to `Vertex`.